# Comparing two excel file with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two excel file, A and B. A is Master copy where updated record of employee Name and Organization Name (`Name` and `Org`) is available. File B contains `Name` and `Org` columns with bit older record and many other columns which we are not interested in.

```
   Name      Org
0   abc    ddc systems
1   sdc    ddc systems
2   csc    ddd systems
3   rdc    kbf org
4   rfc    kbf org
```

I want to do two operation on this:

1) I want to compare Excel B (column `Name` and `Org`) with Excel A (column `Name` and `Org`) and update file B with all the missing entries of `Name` and corresponding `Org`.

2) For all existing entries in File B (column `Name` and `Org`), I would like to compare file and with file A and update `Org` column if any employee organization has changed.

For Solution 1) to find the new entries tried below approach (Not sure if this approach is correct though), output is tuple which I was not sure how to update back to `DataFrame`.

```
diff = set(zip(new_df.Name, new_df.Org)) - set(zip(old_df.Name, old_df.Org))
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are names unique?

Comment: @coldspeed: yes, but while reading file I am renaming the column names

Comment: No, my question was this: "Are the values in the "Name" column always unique in a particular DataFrame, or can you find multiple rows with the same name?".

Comment: @coldspeed: Oh, they are unique !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If names are unique, just concatenate A and B, and drop duplicates. Assuming `A` and `B` are your DataFrames,

```
df = pd.concat([A, B]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep='first')
```

Or,

```
A = A.set_index('Name')
B = B.set_index('Name')

idx = B.index.difference(A.index)
df = pd.concat([A, B.loc[idx]]).reset_index()
```

Both should be approximately the same in terms of performance.

Comment: This is really Cool. this really works for both of my queries.! I am still trying to understand this!

Comment: @tgcloud You can ask if you have any questions.

Comment: `subset=['Name]` will organise `Org` according?

Comment: @tgcloud `.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep='first')` will ensure only the new value is kept and the old value (being a duplicate on Name) is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
diff=pd.DataFrame(list(set(zip(df['aa'], df['bb'])) - set(zip(df2['aa'], df2['bb']))),columns=df.columns)
print(diff.sort_values(by='aa').reset_index(drop=True))
```

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
aa = ['aa1', 'aa2', 'aa3', 'aa4', 'aa5']
bb = ['bb1', 'bb2', 'bb3', 'bb4','bb5']
nest = [aa, bb]
df = pd.DataFrame(nest, ['aa', 'bb']).T
df2 = pd.DataFrame(nest, ['aa', 'bb']).T
df2['aa']=df2['aa'].shift(2)
diff=pd.DataFrame(list(set(zip(df['aa'], df['bb'])) - set(zip(df2['aa'], df2['bb']))),columns=df.columns)
print(diff.sort_values(by='aa').reset_index(drop=True))
```

**Output:**

```
    aa   bb
0  aa1  bb1
1  aa2  bb2
2  aa3  bb3
3  aa4  bb4
4  aa5  bb5
```