# compare two excel files and printing the mismatch values in a new excel using python

Tags: python, excel

First
[image of 1st excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQicB.png)

Second
[image of 2nd excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnt0K.png)

Above are two excel files with two columns each (ID and Type). I want a script to compare the data of the two excel files and then print the mismatch (differences) in another excel file.

Output should be like:
[Click for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9WRQ.png)

Comment: OP, welcome to StackOverflow. Kindly post what have you tried up until now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't added any codes, I assume you haven't tried anything.
Look into documentation of `pandas`.
Open up two files, and then compare the data frame and add discrepancy to a new data frame which you can later same as a new excel file. 
Look at this question.([Comparing two excel file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852514/comparing-two-excel-file-with-pandas))